# Running Node JS application with past date & time scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

One of our NodeJS applications performs various business operations based on current date & time.

It uses JS native Date as well as moment library to perform date-related operations (comparisons, MongoDB query using date range etc.)

During debugging of any issue we want to run the app simulation with past date & time to regenerate the exact scenario.

Straight forward answer to this should be changing the system date & time (OS), & run the application, but there are challenges connecting to various third-party services like MongoDB, Salesforce etc. when the system time is wrong. It gives a CERTIFICATE ERROR.

Other applications running on system are also impacted by this wrong date & time.

To overcome this, I am looking for some kind of time simulation library, that initializes a past clock for my NodeJS app on startup without changing system date & time.

Please suggest something for this.

Tried changing the Operating system date & time to past & running the application. The application runs fine but the integrations break. So I feel that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look into unit testing tools to do that.

For example you can take a look into @sinonjs/fake-timers library: https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers

You can use it like so:

```js
    import FakeTimers from "@sinonjs/fake-timers";
    FakeTimers.install({
        now: new Date("2002-12-21"),
     });
     console.log(new Date()); //2002-12-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

Or use jest: https://jestjs.io/ (jest uses the @sinonjs/fake-timers library)

You can do it like this:

```js
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2002-12-21'));
    const date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
```

Then every new Date instance will be retrieved from the mock.